# Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE not mapping thymeleaf put and delete requests

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

After upgrading from Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE to 2.2.0.RELEASE my Thymeleaf based pages are failing when performing puts and deletes on embedded Tomcat. Gets and posts work fine.

I see in Chrome developer tools that the following request is being sent:

Request URL: https://localhost:8443/notifications/1
Request Method: POST

The request body contains both _method="put" and the _csrf token.

Interestingly my integration tests, annotated with @SpringBootTest, are passing.

Spring Boot Actuator shows /notifications/{notificationId} is mapped to PUT.

Switching back to 2.1.6.RELEASE solves the problem.

My Thymeleaf form is defined as follows:

```
<form id="notificationForm" th:action="@{/notifications/{notificationId}(notificationId=${notification.id})}" th:object="${notification}" th:method="put" class="needs-validation" novalidate autocomplete="off">
```

My controller method is annotated as follows:

```
  @PutMapping("/notifications/{notificationId}")
  public String updateNotification(@PathVariable("notificationId") final Long notificationId,
      @Valid @ModelAttribute(name = NOTIFICATION_MODEL_ATTRIBUTE) final NotificationDto notificationDto,
      final BindingResult result, final Model model, final RedirectAttributes attributes)
```

When I perform the delete the following stack trace is presented in the console:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:367)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:393)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1234)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
...
```

It's as though Spring is not performing the necessary method conversion using _method before resolving the mapping.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

> It's as though Spring is not performing the necessary method conversion using _method before resolving the mapping.

This is exactly what's happening. This conversion is performed by the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` and it is [disabled by default in Spring Boot 2.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#httphiddenmethodfilter-disabled-by-default):

> The filter that handles the `_method` request parameter is now disabled by default as it causes early consumption of a request body if the body may contain parameters. This can be restored by setting either `spring.webflux.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled` or `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled` to true.

You are using Spring MVC so you should set `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true`.